Create a nested list from a dataframe using multiple columns
I have a dataframe that I would like to convert to a nested list, by row. However, I need to group several columns into separate matrices in each nested element. All of the solutions I've seen put each column into a unique element. I want to create separate matrices using the column values.
For example, if I have a dataframe as below:
df = data.frame(a=c("foo", "bar", "baz"), b=1:3, c=3:1, d=4:6, e=6:4)

I'd like to convert it to something like this:
dflist <- list(foo=list(as.matrix(c(1,3)),
                        as.matrix(c(4,6))),
               bar=list(as.matrix(c(2,2)),
                        as.matrix(c(5,5))),
               baz=list(as.matrix(c(3,1)),
                        as.matrix(c(6,4))))


Using purrr:
mylist <- pmap(df, \(b, c, d, e, ...) {
  list(as.matrix(c(b, c)), as.matrix(c(d, e)))
}) |> setNames(df$a)


In base R, you can split and then create your list for each using lapply:
ll <- lapply(split(df, df$a), \(x) list(matrix(x[2:3]), matrix(x[4:5])))

#If order matters (above is alphabetical (bar, bar, foo):
ll_ordered <- ll[match(df$a, names(ll))]

Or all in one line, thanks to the great advice by @Friede:
lapply(split(df, factor(f <- df$a, f)), \(x) list(matrix(x[2:3]), matrix(x[4:5])))

Both approaches give the out output:
# $foo
# $foo[[1]]
# [,1]
# [1,] 1   
# [2,] 3   
# 
# $foo[[2]]
# [,1]
# [1,] 4   
# [2,] 6   
# 
# 
# $bar
# $bar[[1]]
# [,1]
# [1,] 2   
# [2,] 2   
# 
# $bar[[2]]
# [,1]
# [1,] 5   
# [2,] 5   
# 
# 
# $baz
# $baz[[1]]
# [,1]
# [1,] 3   
# [2,] 1   
# 
# $baz[[2]]
# [,1]
# [1,] 6   
# [2,] 4   


For each row create the list of matrices in a new column, data, and then extract that column.  Note that in the question the input is integer but dflist contains doubles.  We assume that was not intended and use dflist as defined in the Note at the end instead.
library(dplyr)

result <- df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(data = list(cbind(c(b, c)), cbind(c(d, e))) %>%
    list %>%
    setNames(a)) %>%
  pull(data)

identical(result, dflist)
## [1] TRUE

Note
dflist <- list(foo=list(as.matrix(c(1L,3L)),
                        as.matrix(c(4L,6L))),
               bar=list(as.matrix(c(2L,2L)),
                        as.matrix(c(5L,5L))),
               baz=list(as.matrix(c(3L,1L)),
                        as.matrix(c(6L,4L))))

